# Updating database table with AJAX on change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update a database column once an input field has changed.
however the code below just isn't doing it and am puzzled.

```
<script>
$("#addline1").change(function() {
                var itemVal = $("#addline1").val();
                var dataString = "companyid=" + companyid + "&addline1=" + itemVal;
                processChange(dataString);
                });
        function processChange(dataString){
                    $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "../inc/dataforms/test.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                complete: function(data) {
                                    var Resp = data.responseText;
                                    console.log(Resp);
                                    }
                    });
    };
</script>
```

`companyid` is already defined elsewhere on the page.
I've tried change, onchange...

My PHP code is:

```
mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE `comp_companies`  SET `regoffice1` = '$_POST[addline1]' 
WHERE `company_id` = '$_POST[companyid]'");
```

Saying unexpected token (
somewhere in here

```
    $("#addline1").change(function() {
        var itemVal = $.("#addline1").val();
        var dataString = "companyid=" + companyid + "&addline1=" + itemVal;
        processChange(dataString)
        });
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: its just not doing anything and its also saying unexpected token ( 
somewhere in the code - see edit above

Comment: `dataString` is declared in the `change` handler. That's why it is `undefined` in the Ajax. Define it globally.

Comment: `dataString` passed as an argument to `processChange`, should work...

Comment: Oups... Ok, you're right.

Comment: `$.("#addline1").val();` here you should remove the dot `.` after dollar `$` at the start of line

Comment: another token error  now  )

Comment: i have var companyid = jsonObject.company_id;
defined further up the page as mentioned

Comment: Ok, can you update your javascript to match what you currently have, now that you fixed the $.( issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an object instead of a string... To pass the data, as the method used is POST.

*(Assuming `companyid` is defined...)*

```
<script>
$("#addline1").change(function() {
  var itemVal = $("#addline1").val();  // Remove the extra dot that was here

  // var dataString = "companyid=" + companyid + "&addline1=" + itemVal;
  // I suggest the following:
  var dataObj = {companyid:companyid, addline1:itemVal};

  processChange(dataObj);
});

function processChange(dataObj){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../inc/dataforms/test.php",
    data: dataObj,
    dataType: "json", // If you expect a json as a response
    complete: function(data) {
      var Resp = data.responseText;
      console.log(Resp);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```